# What are the real-life use cases of JUnit 5 @EnumSource?

Tags: java, junit, junit5

JUnit 5 `@EnumSource` provides a way to use enum constants as parameters for parameterized tests.

However, I'm failing to picture good real-life use cases for this. The documentation examples are only demonstrating how the annotation is used and not really testing anything.

Can you give examples of `@EnumSource` in a real use case?

Answer (score 2):

There is an article about [Burst](https://github.com/square/burst) that provides examples: https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/better-parameterized-tests-with-burst-6f17560013a

It is about JUnit 4 but I think the examples are valuable for JUnit Jupiter's `@EnumSource`, too.